# Customize CheckBox

Tags: android, checkbox

Here is my used CheckBox:

[image]

Here is, what I use to get this check box:

```
<CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
        </CheckBox>
```

I want to customize my CheckBoxes so they become blue, like this:
[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to define a [custom style for your check boxes](http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_change_look_of_checkbox-t4553.html).